# iOS Receipt Validation as a back-end service

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, receipt-validation

Are there any providers of a service for doing iOS receipt validation rather than making your own server (recommended by Apple) or (in iOS 7) doing on-device validation?

I read about [Beeblex](http://thenextweb.com/apple/2012/07/18/developers-beeblex-offers-super-secure-and-completely-free-in-app-purchase-validation-for-ios-apps/), but their web site seems to be out of commission.

Comment: Try Parse.com I haven't used it, but it seems popular.

Answer (score 2):

I recently found [RevenueCat](https://www.revenuecat.com), who offer a receipt validation backend as a service for iOS/macOS and Android.